# How do I treat an ASCII string as unicode and unescape the escaped characters in it in python?

Tags: python, unicode, ascii

For example, if I have a *unicode* string, I can encode it as an *ASCII* string like so:

```
>>> u'\u003cfoo/\u003e'.encode('ascii')
'<foo/>'
```

However, I have e.g. this *ASCII* string:

```
'\u003foo\u003e'
```

... that I want to turn into the same *ASCII* string as in my first example above:

```
'<foo/>'
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It took me a while to figure this one out, but [this page](http://www.egenix.com/www2002/python/unicode-proposal.txt) had the best answer:

```
>>> s = '\u003cfoo/\u003e'
>>> s.decode( 'unicode-escape' )
u'<foo/>'
>>> s.decode( 'unicode-escape' ).encode( 'ascii' )
'<foo/>'
```

There's also a 'raw-unicode-escape' codec to handle the other way to specify Unicode strings -- check the "Unicode Constructors" section of the linked page for more details (since I'm not that Unicode-saavy).

EDIT: See also [Python Standard Encodings](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/standard-encodings.html).

Comment: Note that it only applies to Python 2. In Python 3, all strings are unicode objects https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28583565/str-object-has-no-attribute-decode-python-3-error

Answer (score 2):

On Python 2.5 the correct encoding is "unicode_escape", not "unicode-escape" (note the underscore).

I'm not sure if the newer version of Python changed the unicode name, but here only worked with the underscore.

Anyway, this is it.

Answer (score 2):

At some point you will run into issues when you encounter special characters like Chinese characters or emoticons in a string you want to decode i.e. errors that look like this:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 109-123: ordinal not in range(128)
```

For my case (twitter data processing), I decoded as follows to allow me to see all characters with no errors

```
>>> s = '\u003cfoo\u003e'
>>> s.decode( 'unicode-escape' ).encode( 'utf-8' )
>>> <foo>
```

Answer (score 1):

*Ned Batchelder* said:

> It's a little dangerous depending on where the string is coming from,
>   but how about:
>
> ```
> >>> s = '\u003cfoo\u003e'
> >>> eval('u"'+s.replace('"', r'\"')+'"').encode('ascii')
> '<foo>'
> ```

Actually this method can be made safe like so:

```
>>> s = '\u003cfoo\u003e'
>>> s_unescaped = eval('u"""'+s.replace('"', r'\"')+'-"""')[:-1]
```

Mind the triple-quote string and the dash right before the closing 3-quotes.

1. Using a 3-quoted string will ensure that if the user enters ' \\" ' (spaces added for visual clarity) in the string it would not disrupt the evaluator;
2. The dash at the end is a failsafe in case the user's string ends with a ' \" ' . Before we assign the result we slice the inserted dash with [:-1]

So there would be no need to worry about what the users enter, as long as it is captured in raw format.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little dangerous depending on where the string is coming from, but how about:

```
>>> s = '\u003cfoo\u003e'
>>> eval('u"'+s.replace('"', r'\"')+'"').encode('ascii')
'<foo>'
```

Comment: Unfortunately our input is coming from users so this would be too dangerous for us.