# Python string to unicode

Tags: python, string, unicode, python-2.x, python-unicode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I treat an ASCII string as unicode and unescape the escaped characters in it in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267436/how-do-i-treat-an-ascii-string-as-unicode-and-unescape-the-escaped-characters-in)
>   [How do convert unicode escape sequences to unicode characters in a python string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990169/how-do-convert-unicode-escape-sequences-to-unicode-characters-in-a-python-string)

I have a string that contains unicode characters e.g. `\u2026` etc. Somehow it is not received to me as `unicode`, but is received as a `str`. How do I convert it back to unicode?

```
>>> a="Hello\u2026"
>>> b=u"Hello\u2026"
>>> print a
Hello\u2026
>>> print b
Hello…
>>> print unicode(a)
Hello\u2026
>>>
```

So clearly `unicode(a)` is not the answer. Then what is?

Comment: The tag says so, but to point out more clearly, this question is focused on python 2.x, not 3.x.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Unicode escapes only work in unicode strings, so this

```
 a="\u2026"
```

is actually a string of 6 characters: '\', 'u', '2', '0', '2', '6'.

To make unicode out of this, use `decode('unicode-escape')`:

```
a="\u2026"
print repr(a)
print repr(a.decode('unicode-escape'))

## '\\u2026'
## u'\u2026'
```

Answer (score 28):

Decode it with the `unicode-escape` codec:

```
>>> a="Hello\u2026"
>>> a.decode('unicode-escape')
u'Hello\u2026'
>>> print _
Hello…
```

This is because for a non-unicode string the `\u2026` is not recognised but is instead treated as a literal series of characters (to put it more clearly, `'Hello\\u2026'`). You need to decode the escapes, and the `unicode-escape` codec can do that for you.

Note that you can get `unicode` to recognise it in the same way by specifying the codec argument:

```
>>> unicode(a, 'unicode-escape')
u'Hello\u2026'
```

But the `a.decode()` way is nicer.

Answer (score 17):

```
>>> a="Hello\u2026"
>>> print a.decode('unicode-escape')
Hello…
```