# Python Unicode string stored as '\u84b8\u6c7d\u5730' in file, how to convert it back to Unicode?

Tags: python, unicode

Some Unicode data is stored in file as '\u84b8\u6c7d\u5730' without any encoding.

Is there a way to covert them back in Python?

Comment: Do you mean `'\\u84b8\\u6c7d\\u5730'` or as `u'\u84b8\u6c7d\u5730'`?

Comment: @Chris: No need to escape the backslashes, as `\u` isn't a valid escape in bytestrings.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: I know; I put it with the doubled backslashes to make my meaning more obvious

Comment: As you've accepted Ignacio's answer, this must be a duplicate of [How do I treat an ASCII string as unicode and unescape the escaped characters in it in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267436/how-do-i-treat-an-ascii-string-as-unicode-and-unescape-the-escaped-characters-in)

Comment: I agree. I just cannot find out the right article for this issue.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
>>> print '\u84b8\u6c7d\u5730'.decode('unicode-escape')
蒸汽地
```

Comment: I think this is probably what he means, but I'm not sure... if it is, it's a duplicate, anyway.

Comment: That's good. Here's another alternate form: `s= unicode('\u84b8\u6c7d\u5730', "unicode-escape")`.

Comment: I spent a lot of time trying to solve this problem, now I saw your solution!

Comment: amazing! This should have been part of the lengthy treatise on handling unicode in python. Standard docs are lacking on this fix.

Comment: `print(u'\u84b8\u6c7d\u5730')`

Answer (score 1):

This code helped me to decode the string in Python 3:

```
text = '\\u041d\\u0435\\u0442 \\u043f\\u0430\\u0440\\u0430\\u043c\\u0435\\u0442\\u0440\\u0430'
res = text.encode().decode('unicode_escape')
print(res)
```

- `encode()` - convert a `str` to a `bytes` object
- `decode('unicode_escape')` - convert a `bytes` object to a `str` using codec `unicode_escape`. See [Python 3 Standard Encodings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings).