# How could I save the html-like string from POST request's response

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, lxml

I made a POST request with Python requests and got the following html-like response.

How could I read the strange response in LXML or BeautifulSoup?

```
"\r\n\u003cdiv class=\"stepbar1\"\u003e\r\n\t\u003cul\u003e\r\n\t\t\u003cli class=\"step1\"\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"stepactive\"\u003e\r\n                Search Result\r\n            \u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"flightstepactive\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\u003c/li\u003e\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t\u003cli class=\"step2\"\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\u003cdiv\u003e\r\n                Passenger Details\r\n            \u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"personalstep\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\u003c/li\u003e\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t\u003cli class=\"step3\"\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\u003cdiv\u003e\r\n                Seat Selection\r\n            \u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"seatstep\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\u003c/li\u003e\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t\u003cli class=\"step4\"\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\u003cdiv\u003e\r\n                Payment\r\n            \u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"purchasestep\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\u003c/li\u003e\r\n\t\u003c/ul\u003e\r\n\r\n\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\r\n\u003cdiv class=\"CoverDetailPopup\"\u003e\r\n    \u003cinput id=\"dvClientOnHold\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"0\" /\u003e\r\n    \r\n\t\r\n    \u003cdiv class=\"clear-all\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\u003cdiv class=\"Availability\"\u003e\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"FareUpSell\"\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv id=\"tabs\"\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"HappPlusTitle\"\u003e\r\n\t\t\t     \t    Happy Peach\r\n                        \u003cspan class=\"green\"\u003ePlus\u003c/span\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"HappyPlusDetail\"\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv\u003e1 Free Checked Bag\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv\u003eFree Seat Selection\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv\u003eLast minute booking\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"HappyPlusDetail\"\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv\u003eUnlimited Flight Changes\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv\u003eRefund on Cancellation\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"nolist\"\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003ca href=\"javascript:ShowTermUpFareSell();\"\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t      *Terms and conditions apply\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003c/a\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\u003cul\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003cli\u003e\u003ca href=\"#tabs-1\"\u003eClick!\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/li\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\u003c/ul\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv id=\"tabs-1\"\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"HappyPlusInside\"\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"InsideTitle\"\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t      1 Free Checked Bag\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"InsideDetail\"\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t      20kg max, sum of the three dimensions of 203 cm\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"InsideTitle\"\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t      Free Seat Selection\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"InsideDetail\"\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t      Free Standard or Pleasure Seat selection\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"InsideTitle\"\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t      Last minute booking\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"InsideDetail\"\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t      Possible to book flight up to 1 hr before departure\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"HappyPlusInside\"\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"InsideTitle\"\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t      Unlimited Flight Changes\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"InsideDetail\"\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t      Unlimited flight changes via internet with no change fee\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n                                \u003cbr/\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t      (fare difference charged)\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"InsideTitle\"\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t      Refund on Cancellation\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"InsideDetail\"\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t      Refunded with Peach Point back on booking cancellation (cancel fee charged)\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"clear-all\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"clear-all\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\r\n\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"clear-all\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\r\n\t    \u003cdiv id=\"ctl00_dvOutwardResult\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"FlightAvailability\" xmlns:JCode=\"http://www.tiksystems.com/B2C\" xmlns:msxsl=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt\" xmlns:tikLanguage=\"tik:Language\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"WrapperTBLYourFlight\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"BoxtopleftCorner\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"Boxtopmiddle\"\u003e\u003cinput type=\"hidden\" id=\"hdNumberOfTransit\" value=\"0\" name=\"hdNumberOfTransit\"\u003eDeparture Flights : \r\n            \u003cspan class=\"TextFlightName\"\u003eOsaka - Kansai (KIX)\u003c/span\u003e\r\n           To \r\n          \u003cspan class=\"TextFlightName\"\u003eTaipei - Taoyuan (TPE)\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"BoxtoprightCorner\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"LoadingDisable\"\u003e\u003cdiv id=\"Outward_loading\" class=\"loadingImage\"\u003e\u003cimg src=\"App_Themes/Default/Images/loading.gif\" alt=\"\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv id=\"graygradient\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"AvailabilitySearch\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"WrapperTBLSelectNewFlight\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"WrapperFlightDate\"\u003e\u003cdiv id=\"Outward_DatePrevious\" class=\"dateback\"\u003e\u003ca href=\"javascript:SearchSingleFlight(\u002720160216\u0027, \u0027Outward\u0027);\"\u003e\u003cimg src=\"App_Themes/Default/Images/dateback.png\" alt=\"Previous 3 days\" title=\"Previous 3 days\"\u003e\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"showdategroup\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"showdate\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"flighttime\" onClick=\"SearchSingleFlight(\u002720160218\u0027, \u0027Outward\u0027);\"\u003e02/18 (Thu)\u003cdiv class=\"price\"\u003e\r\n\t                            ¥\r\n\t                          11,380~\r\n\t                      \u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cinput type=\"hidden\" id=\"Outward_hdSelectedDate\" value=\"20160219\" name=\"hdSelectedDate\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"showdateselect\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"dateouterbox\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"flighttimeSelect\"\u003e02/19 (Fri)\u003cdiv class=\"price\"\u003e\r\n\t                              ¥\r\n\t                            10,080~\r\n\t                        \u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"clear-all\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"showdate\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"flighttime\" onClick=\"SearchSingleFlight(\u002720160220\u0027, \u0027Outward\u0027);\"\u003e02/20 (Sat)\u003cdiv class=\"price\"\u003e\r\n                            ¥\r\n                          11,380~\r\n                      \u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"datenext\"\u003e\u003ca href=\"javascript:SearchSingleFlight(\u002720160222\u0027, \u0027Outward\u0027);\"\u003e\u003cimg src=\"App_Themes/Default/Images/datenext.png\" alt=\"Next 3 days\" title=\"Next 3 days\"\u003e\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"clear-all\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"clear-all\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003ctable class=\"TBLYourFlight\"\u003e\u003ctr class=\"FlightHeader\"\u003e\u003ctd class=\"HeadCOL1 Last\"\u003e\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd class=\"HeadCOL4 Last\"\u003e\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd class=\"HeadCOL6 Last\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"demoB\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"fg-tooltip ui-widget ui-widget-tooltip ui-corner-all\" style=\"display: none;\"\u003e\u003cul class=\"tooltipcontent\"\u003e\u003cli\u003eChild (2-11years): Same price as adult\u003c/li\u003e\u003cli\u003ePurchase Deadline: 0:00AM (local airport time) at least 1 day before boarding date\u003cbr\u003e(Promo Fares are limited time offers)\u003c/li\u003e\u003cli\u003eChanges: Fee applies (per changed flight)\u003c/li\u003e\u003cli\u003eRefund: Non-refundable\u003c/li\u003e\u003cli\u003eBaggage: Fee applies\u003c/li\u003e\u003cli\u003eAdvance Seat selection: Fee applies\u003c/li\u003e\u003c/ul\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"fg-tooltip-pointer-down ui-widget-tooltip\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"fg-tooltip-pointer-down-inner\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cp class=\"demoText\"\u003e\u003ca href=\"#\" class=\"tooltip\"\u003eHappy Peach\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd class=\"HeadCOL7 Last\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"demoC\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"fg-tooltip ui-widget ui-widget-tooltip ui-corner-all\" style=\"display: none;\"\u003e\u003cul class=\"tooltipcontent\"\u003e\u003cli\u003eChild (2-11years): Same price as adult\u003c/li\u003e\u003cli\u003ePurchase Deadline: 1hour before departure\u003c/li\u003e\u003cli\u003eChanges: Unlimited Free via internet only\u003c/li\u003e\u003cli\u003eRefund: Only refundable to Peach Points (fee applies)\u003c/li\u003e\u003cli\u003eBaggage: Free (1 piece per person, max 20kg)\u003c/li\u003e\u003cli\u003eAdvance Seat selection: Free (standard and pleasure seats only )\u003c/li\u003e\u003c/ul\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"fg-tooltip-pointer-down ui-widget-tooltip\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"fg-tooltip-pointer-down-inner\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cp class=\"demoText\"\u003e\u003ca href=\"#\" class=\"tooltip\"\u003eHappy Peach\u003cspan class=\"plustext\"\u003e Plus\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/td\u003e\u003c/tr\u003e\u003ctr class=\"FlightInformation1\"\u003e\u003ctd class=\"BodyCOL1 Last\" title=\"\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"FlightdurationDetail Oldflight\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"Flightdurationtooltip\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"fg-tooltip ui-widget ui-widget-tooltip ui-corner-all\" style=\"display: none;\"\u003e\u003cul class=\"tooltipcontent\"\u003e\u003cli\u003eFlight \r\n                              MM023\u003c/li\u003e\u003cli\u003eDep : \r\n                              \r\n      07:50\u003c/li\u003e\u003cli\u003eArr : \r\n                              10:00\u003c/li\u003e\u003cli\u003eFlight Duration : \r\n                              3 \r\n    Hour \r\n    10 \r\n    Minute \r\n  \u003c/li\u003e\u003cli\u003eAircraft : \r\n                              A320\u003c/li\u003e\u003cli\u003eCheck in 30 mins before departure for Domestic flight and 50 mins for International flight.\u003c/li\u003e\u003c/ul\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"fg-tooltip-pointer-down ui-widget-tooltip\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"fg-tooltip-pointer-down-inner\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cp class=\"demoText\"\u003e\u003ca href=\"#\" class=\"tooltip\" onclick=\"return false;\"\u003eMM023\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd class=\"BodyCOL4\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"FlightDuration\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"FlightdurationDetail Deptflight\"\u003eDept. \r\n              02/19 \r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n      07:50 \r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\tOsaka - Kansai\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"clear-all\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"FlightdurationDetail Arrivflight\"\u003eArriv. \r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t02/19 \r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t10:00 \r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tTaipei - Taoyuan\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd class=\"BodyCOL6\" id=\"Outward1_1\"\u003e\u003cinput id=\"optOutward1_1\" name=\"Outward\" type=\"radio\" value=\"flight_id:{F6D0A161-6B4F-420F-82AF-BAA48AB8FC73}|fare_id:{9310DBBE-0771-4064-BF06-5C044D9B2931}|boarding_class_rcd:Y|booking_class_rcd:N|airline_rcd:MM|flight_number:023|origin_rcd:KIX|destination_rcd:TPE|departure_date:20160219|planned_departure_time:750|planned_arrival_time:1000|transit_airline_rcd:|transit_flight_number:|transit_airport_rcd:|transit_boarding_class_rcd:|transit_booking_class_rcd:|transit_flight_id:|transit_fare_id:|transit_planned_departure_time:|transit_planned_arrival_time:|total_tax:0.00|adult_fare:16580|child_fare:16580|infant_fare:0.0000|transit_departure_date:|arrival_date:20160219|number_of_adult:1|number_of_child:0|number_of_infant:0|currency_rcd:JPY|transit_arrival_date:\" onclick=\"GetQuoteSummary(this, \u0027Outward\u0027, \u0027Outward1_1\u0027)\"\u003e\u003clabel for=\"optOutward1_1\"\u003e\r\n                                  ¥\r\n                                16,580\u003c/label\u003e\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd class=\"BodyCOL7\" id=\"Outward1_2\"\u003e\u003cinput id=\"optOutward1_2\" name=\"Outward\" type=\"radio\" value=\"flight_id:{F6D0A161-6B4F-420F-82AF-BAA48AB8FC73}|fare_id:{0EFB161A-364A-43FC-9D2D-5F8A06B2C4D3}|boarding_class_rcd:Y|booking_class_rcd:N|airline_rcd:MM|flight_number:023|origin_rcd:KIX|destination_rcd:TPE|departure_date:20160219|planned_departure_time:750|planned_arrival_time:1000|transit_airline_rcd:|transit_flight_number:|transit_airport_rcd:|transit_boarding_class_rcd:|transit_booking_class_rcd:|transit_flight_id:|transit_fare_id:|transit_planned_departure_time:|transit_planned_arrival_time:|total_tax:0.00|adult_fare:23280|child_fare:23280|infant_fare:0.0000|transit_departure_date:|arrival_date:20160219|number_of_adult:1|number_of_child:0|number_of_infant:0|currency_rcd:JPY|transit_arrival_date:\" onclick=\"GetQuoteSummary(this, \u0027Outward\u0027, \u0027Outward1_2\u0027)\"\u003e\u003clabel for=\"optOutward1_2\"\u003e\r\n                                  ¥\r\n                                23,280\u003c/label\u003e\u003c/td\u003e\u003c/tr\u003e\u003ctr class=\"FlightInformation0\"\u003e\u003ctd class=\"BodyCOL1 Last\" title=\"\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"FlightdurationDetail Oldflight\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"Flightdurationtooltip\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"fg-tooltip ui-widget ui-widget-tooltip ui-corner-all\" style=\"display: none;\"\u003e\u003cul class=\"tooltipcontent\"\u003e\u003cli\u003eFlight \r\n                              MM027\u003c/li\u003e\u003cli\u003eDep : \r\n                              16:05\u003c/li\u003e\u003cli\u003eArr : \r\n                              18:15\u003c/li\u003e\u003cli\u003eFlight Duration : \r\n                              3 \r\n    Hour \r\n    10 \r\n    Minute \r\n  \u003c/li\u003e\u003cli\u003eAircraft : \r\n                              A320\u003c/li\u003e\u003cli\u003eCheck in 30 mins before departure for Domestic flight and 50 mins for International flight.\u003c/li\u003e\u003c/ul\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"fg-tooltip-pointer-down ui-widget-tooltip\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"fg-tooltip-pointer-down-inner\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cp class=\"demoText\"\u003e\u003ca href=\"#\" class=\"tooltip\" onclick=\"return false;\"\u003eMM027\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd class=\"BodyCOL4\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"FlightDuration\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"FlightdurationDetail Deptflight\"\u003eDept. \r\n              02/19 \r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t16:05 \r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\tOsaka - Kansai\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"clear-all\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"FlightdurationDetail Arrivflight\"\u003eArriv. \r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t02/19 \r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t18:15 \r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tTaipei - Taoyuan\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd class=\"BodyCOL6\" id=\"Outward2_1\"\u003e\u003cinput id=\"optOutward2_1\" name=\"Outward\" type=\"radio\" value=\"flight_id:{11B38FE7-95C6-4808-B5A4-AF763E1FC211}|fare_id:{43BC11C9-F2F5-4C91-BD31-74C708EE70B5}|boarding_class_rcd:Y|booking_class_rcd:R|airline_rcd:MM|flight_number:027|origin_rcd:KIX|destination_rcd:TPE|departure_date:20160219|planned_departure_time:1605|planned_arrival_time:1815|transit_airline_rcd:|transit_flight_number:|transit_airport_rcd:|transit_boarding_class_rcd:|transit_booking_class_rcd:|transit_flight_id:|transit_fare_id:|transit_planned_departure_time:|transit_planned_arrival_time:|total_tax:0.00|adult_fare:11380|child_fare:11380|infant_fare:0.0000|transit_departure_date:|arrival_date:20160219|number_of_adult:1|number_of_child:0|number_of_infant:0|currency_rcd:JPY|transit_arrival_date:\" onclick=\"GetQuoteSummary(this, \u0027Outward\u0027, \u0027Outward2_1\u0027)\"\u003e\u003clabel for=\"optOutward2_1\"\u003e\r\n                                  ¥\r\n                                11,380\u003c/label\u003e\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd class=\"BodyCOL7\" id=\"Outward2_2\"\u003e\u003cinput id=\"optOutward2_2\" name=\"Outward\" type=\"radio\" value=\"flight_id:{11B38FE7-95C6-4808-B5A4-AF763E1FC211}|fare_id:{BDC9CD21-35EA-4797-AFF9-1C64AC2BE59C}|boarding_class_rcd:Y|booking_class_rcd:R|airline_rcd:MM|flight_number:027|origin_rcd:KIX|destination_rcd:TPE|departure_date:20160219|planned_departure_time:1605|planned_arrival_time:1815|transit_airline_rcd:|transit_flight_number:|transit_airport_rcd:|transit_boarding_class_rcd:|transit_booking_class_rcd:|transit_flight_id:|transit_fare_id:|transit_planned_departure_time:|transit_planned_arrival_time:|total_tax:0.00|adult_fare:15480|child_fare:15480|infant_fare:0.0000|transit_departure_date:|arrival_date:20160219|number_of_adult:1|number_of_child:0|number_of_infant:0|currency_rcd:JPY|transit_arrival_date:\" onclick=\"GetQuoteSummary(this, \u0027Outward\u0027, \u0027Outward2_2\u0027)\"\u003e\u003clabel for=\"optOutward2_2\"\u003e\r\n                                  ¥\r\n                                15,480\u003c/label\u003e\u003c/td\u003e\u003c/tr\u003e\u003ctr class=\"FlightInformation1\"\u003e\u003ctd class=\"BodyCOL1 Last\" title=\"\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"FlightdurationDetail Oldflight\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"Flightdurationtooltip\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"fg-tooltip ui-widget ui-widget-tooltip ui-corner-all\" style=\"display: none;\"\u003e\u003cul class=\"tooltipcontent\"\u003e\u003cli\u003eFlight \r\n                              MM029\u003c/li\u003e\u003cli\u003eDep : \r\n                              20:50\u003c/li\u003e\u003cli\u003eArr : \r\n                              23:00\u003c/li\u003e\u003cli\u003eFlight Duration : \r\n                              3 \r\n    Hour \r\n    10 \r\n    Minute \r\n  \u003c/li\u003e\u003cli\u003eAircraft : \r\n                              A320\u003c/li\u003e\u003cli\u003eCheck in 30 mins before departure for Domestic flight and 50 mins for International flight.\u003c/li\u003e\u003c/ul\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"fg-tooltip-pointer-down ui-widget-tooltip\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"fg-tooltip-pointer-down-inner\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cp class=\"demoText\"\u003e\u003ca href=\"#\" class=\"tooltip\" onclick=\"return false;\"\u003eMM029\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd class=\"BodyCOL4\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"FlightDuration\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"FlightdurationDetail Deptflight\"\u003eDept. \r\n              02/19 \r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t20:50 \r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\tOsaka - Kansai\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"clear-all\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"FlightdurationDetail Arrivflight\"\u003eArriv. \r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t02/19 \r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t23:00 \r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tTaipei - Taoyuan\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd class=\"BodyCOL6\" id=\"Outward3_1\"\u003e\u003cinput id=\"optOutward3_1\" name=\"Outward\" type=\"radio\" value=\"flight_id:{BF1CAE71-785F-419A-BFFA-6E072BEF28A8}|fare_id:{7FD7FB8F-70D9-438C-A00B-89479EE15E44}|boarding_class_rcd:Y|booking_class_rcd:S|airline_rcd:MM|flight_number:029|origin_rcd:KIX|destination_rcd:TPE|departure_date:20160219|planned_departure_time:2050|planned_arrival_time:2300|transit_airline_rcd:|transit_flight_number:|transit_airport_rcd:|transit_boarding_class_rcd:|transit_booking_class_rcd:|transit_flight_id:|transit_fare_id:|transit_planned_departure_time:|transit_planned_arrival_time:|total_tax:0.00|adult_fare:10080|child_fare:10080|infant_fare:0.0000|transit_departure_date:|arrival_date:20160219|number_of_adult:1|number_of_child:0|number_of_infant:0|currency_rcd:JPY|transit_arrival_date:\" onclick=\"GetQuoteSummary(this, \u0027Outward\u0027, \u0027Outward3_1\u0027)\"\u003e\u003clabel for=\"optOutward3_1\"\u003e\r\n                                  ¥\r\n                                10,080\u003c/label\u003e\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd class=\"BodyCOL7\" id=\"Outward3_2\"\u003e\u003cinput id=\"optOutward3_2\" name=\"Outward\" type=\"radio\" value=\"flight_id:{BF1CAE71-785F-419A-BFFA-6E072BEF28A8}|fare_id:{CC7918C5-AE6A-4838-A29E-0F7654252B21}|boarding_class_rcd:Y|booking_class_rcd:S|airline_rcd:MM|flight_number:029|origin_rcd:KIX|destination_rcd:TPE|departure_date:20160219|planned_departure_time:2050|planned_arrival_time:2300|transit_airline_rcd:|transit_flight_number:|transit_airport_rcd:|transit_boarding_class_rcd:|transit_booking_class_rcd:|transit_flight_id:|transit_fare_id:|transit_planned_departure_time:|transit_planned_arrival_time:|total_tax:0.00|adult_fare:14180|child_fare:14180|infant_fare:0.0000|transit_departure_date:|arrival_date:20160219|number_of_adult:1|number_of_child:0|number_of_infant:0|currency_rcd:JPY|transit_arrival_date:\" onclick=\"GetQuoteSummary(this, \u0027Outward\u0027, \u0027Outward3_2\u0027)\"\u003e\u003clabel for=\"optOutward3_2\"\u003e\r\n                                  ¥\r\n                                14,180\u003c/label\u003e\u003c/td\u003e\u003c/tr\u003e\u003c/table\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"clear-all\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"clear-all\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"BottomBox\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"BoxdownleftCorner\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"BoxdownmiddleCorner\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"BoxdownrightCorner\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"clear-all\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t    \u003cdiv class=\"clear-all\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t    \u003cdiv id=\"ctl00_dvReturnResult\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"clear-all\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t\u003cdiv id=\"dvComboFlightInfo\" class=\"AvailabilityContent\" style=\"display:none;\"\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"FlightSelectiontopleftCorner\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"FlightSelectiontopmiddle\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"FlightSelectiontoprightCorner\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"clear-all\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\r\n\t\t\t\u003cdiv id=\"flightselectiongradient\"\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"whitebox\"\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"whiteboxtopleft\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"whiteboxtopcontent\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"whiteboxtopright\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"clear-all\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"innerwhitebox\"\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"flightselectioncontent\"\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"Comboflight-Title\"\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tAbout Combo Flight\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"Comboflight-content\"\u003e\r\n                                For passenger with checked baggage, you will need to collect your baggage on arrival at the connecting airport and re-check it in for your connecting flight. Passengers without checked baggage will still need to be checked-in before their second flight\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tFor international connections, you will need to pass through Immigration and Customs. You are responsible for having all required travel documents (passport, visa etc.)\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003c/div\u003e\r\n                            \r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"clear-all\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"ComboFlightRule\"\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003cinput id=\"chkComboFlight\" type=\"checkbox\" /\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003clabel for=\"chkComboFlight\"\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tYes I have read and understand Peach Combo Flight Rule.\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003c/label\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"clear-all\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"BottominnerBox\"\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"whiteboxbottomleft\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"whiteboxbottomcontent\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"whiteboxbottomright\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"clear-all\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\r\n\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"clear-all\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\r\n\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"BottomBox\"\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"BoxdownleftCorner\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"BoxdownmiddleCorner\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"BoxdownrightCorner\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\r\n\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"clear-all\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\r\n\t\t\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"clear-all\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\r\n\t        \u003cdiv class=\"Notification\"\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"BoxtopleftCorner\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"Boxtopmiddle\"\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\tNotification\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"BoxtoprightCorner\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"clear-all\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"NotificationContent\"\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"paymentcontent\"\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\tPrices are per person, and do not include fees, taxes, and other charges.\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\tPlease note the minimum connecting times between Peach flights as follows: \u003cbr\u003eDOMESTIC to DOMESTIC: 60 min\u003cbr\u003e INTERNATIONAL to INTERNATIONAL: 90 min\u003cbr\u003e DOMESTIC to INTERNATIONAL: 90 min\u003cbr\u003eINTERNATIONAL to DOMESTIC: 90 min\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003c/div\u003e\r\n                        \u003cbr /\u003e\r\n                        \u003cdiv\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\tIt is your responsibility to ensure you have sufficient time to connect onward flights including other airlines. \u003cbr\u003ePeach shall not be liable for any compensation under any circumstances such as delays or flight cancellations.\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"clear-all\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\u003c/div\u003e\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"clear-all\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"clear-all\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"BTN-Search\"\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\u003cdiv class=\"continuetext-noback\"\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\tBy clicking \"next\" you understand and accept Peach Aviation Limited\r\n                \u003ca href=\"http://www.flypeach.com/conditionsofcarriage.aspx\" target=\"_blank\"\u003econditions of carriage\u003c/a\u003e,\r\n                \u003ca href=\"http://www.flypeach.com/fares/faretypes.aspx\" target=\"_blank\"\u003efare rules\u003c/a\u003e,\r\n                \u003ca href=\"http://www.flypeach.com/privacypolicy.aspx\" target=\"_blank\"\u003eprivacy\u003c/a\u003e and\r\n                \u003ca href=\"http://www.flypeach.com/termsandconditions.aspx\" target=\"_blank\"\u003ewebsite usage\u003c/a\u003e, \u003ca href=\"http://www.flypeach.com/Portals/1/images/danger/img_danger_en.jpg\"target=\"_blank\"\u003edangerous goods\u003c/a\u003e\r\n                policies.\r\n\t\t\t\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\u003cdiv id=\"dvAvaiNext\" class=\"ButtonAlignRight\"\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\u003ca href=\"javascript:SelectFlight();\" title=\"Next\" class=\"processbutton\"\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\u003cspan\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\tNext\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\u003c/span\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\t\u003c/a\u003e\r\n\t\t\t\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\t\t\u003c/div\u003e\r\n\r\n    \u003c/div\u003e\r\n   \r\n\u003c/div\u003e"
```

Answer (score 1):

It is just encoded in unicode. Assuming your response was in variable called "resp" you can print that as:

```
print resp.decode( 'unicode-escape' )
```

Also see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267436/how-do-i-treat-an-ascii-string-as-unicode-and-unescape-the-escaped-characters-in).

Comment: `resp.text.decode( 'unicode-escape' )`
*** AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode', resp is the object returned by requests

Comment: Works for me, using python 2.7. I just assign to resp the value in quotes that you provided, and by all means that is a type(str).
If you can provide a way to test the whole requests, then I might be able to help, otherwise I hope this at least takes you in the right direction.

Comment: oh, sorry, I forgot to mention that i'm using python 3

Comment: I am not very versed in python3 and the whole encoding/decoding thing, plus I see there's changes in there. Reading some of the documentation in here (https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str) you may need to check what `type` the `resp.text` comes back as, and then try some variations. Even in py3, this seems to work, but writing to file might need some additional massaging https://eval.in/514213